# Improving mktemp

Tags: bash, mktemp

I am wondering how to best improve on `mktemp` for use with encrypted containers or file systems.

The issue that I am dealing with is that I would like my shell scripts to store temporary files inside the file system that contains the working directory, if possible.

The normal behaviour of `mktemp` seems to be to use a root path specified in an environment variables or `/tmp`. This will, however, routinely leak temporary data to unencrypted locations if I am working with files inside encrypted containers.

The idea is to first check the presence of a `tmp` directory in the mount point of the current file system and to use `/tmp`only as a last resort. How can I reliably (and efficiently) realize that.

**Edit**

A possible way to identify the mount directory of a given path is the following

```
dir=`realpath [path]`; 
res=1; 
while [ $res -ne 0 ]; do 
  dir="${dir%/*}"; 
  mountpoint -q "$dir/"; 
  res=$?; 
done; 
echo "$dir";
```

I am not sure, however, if that is the most efficient one.

Comment: Why not just encrypt /tmp, or use tmpfs so it stays in ram?

Comment: My tmp is already encrypted, but with a security policy different from the differing policies of the various containers, so it won't help. For the same reason, I would need a different tmpfs for each container.

Comment: When you say "container" are you talking about LXC containers?  If so, then yes, they absolutely should each have their own /tmp.

Comment: You may think of truecrypt containers or volumes mounted somewhere in a users home directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify any directory to `mktemp`; either using the -p option or setting a different TMPDIR.

```
-p temp-dir, --tmpdir=temp-dir
          temp  directory  for  the  file.  This option is a member of the
          tmpdir class of options.

          If this option is not provided, mktemp will use the  environment
          variable  TMPDIR to find a suitable directory.  If these are not
          available, it will fall back to ~/tmp  or  /tmp.   A  <file-pat>
          command line argument containing a directory component will con-
          flict with this option.
```

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPDIR=`pwd`
mktemp
```

Comment: OK, need to try that.  My man page reads a little bit differently. Will it find a tmp directory in a super directory of pwd if there is none in pwd itself?

Comment: Try it and see how it behaves.

Comment: Tried it. On my system, `TMPDIR=`pwd`; export TMPDIR; mktemp` will create a temporary file in `pwd`. This is not the behaviour that I want, since it will create temporary files everywhere. Perhaps that is better than leaking confidential information to directories that are not encrypted. However, I would still prefer to have my temporary files in a central location for each container.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your requirement, you want `mktemp /WORKING/DIR/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX` or however you want the name to be like (every `X` is replaced by a random alphanumeric character).

Comment: No. I want to use tmp dirs which are present. Creating a temporary path in the working directory entails that I mix the temporary files with persistent ones. E.g., a sync job would copy those temporary files unless I modify it. I need to ensure, however, that the temporary files are not created in a different resource.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. I don't see how to improve much on the code you supplied in the question.